# Sencha touch 2 slider events continuous change event

Tags: slider, sencha-touch-2

Is there a possibility to get the normal html5 change event for the sencha touch slider as well? Sencha touch 2 offers a change event which is only fired once the slider is dropped.

I want to use it for turning on and off the lights smoothly, the slider should be continuous. Is there an easy way to do this?

We did this in pure html, we limited the events by adding steps of 10 to a 0-100 slider. I hope i have not to build my own component.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`drag`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.field.Slider-event-drag) event on `Ext.field.Slider`.

Comment: thank you, i missed that because i thought it is a kind of dragstart event. I liked your component dataview example on github